# How to prevent layout from stretching when running on qHD (540x960)?

Tags: layout, android-layout

I have a nice LinearLayout which runs as expected on 480x800 screens.
The layout contains three main sections: top, middle and bottom.
When running in qHD the top layout becomes longer (higher). I want the top layout to keep its height as in 480x800 and that the extra space will be 'added' to the end of the screen.
I will try to show in the attached image.
[image: layout]

the top layout height is 'match parent'

middle: 35dp

bottom: 'wrap_content'

Now, I thought, maybe changing the top layout to 'wrap_content' so I did but in order to test it i just change the configuration in the layout design screen, to larger screens and it looks like it keeps stretching the top layout,

How do i do it, or make sure the top layout won't stretch in height 540?
Thanks, Eran.

here is my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout style="@style/TitleBar" >

        <ImageView
            style="@style/TitleBarLogo"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_home"
            android:onClick="onClickHome"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView style="@style/TitleBarText" />

        <ImageButton
            style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_actionbar_item_map" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- page header -->
    <include layout="@layout/page_header"/>


    <!-- Layout1 -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llrow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="true" >

        <!-- Layout1.1 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" >

                        <!-- Layout1.1.1 -->

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="118dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                            android:layout_weight="0.98"
                            android:baselineAligned="false"
                            android:gravity="top|right"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:paddingRight="2dp"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                            <!-- Layout1.1.1.1 -->
                            <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                            android:paddingRight="5dp"
                            android:gravity="top|right"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" 
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                                <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/heartImg"
                                android:layout_gravity="top"
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/heart"
                                />

                                <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/itemHeaderTitle"
                                style="@style/ItemTitle"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                            </LinearLayout><!-- end Layout1.1.1.1 -->

                            <!-- Layout1.1.1.2 -->
                            <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/llRecommended"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                            android:paddingRight="5dp"
                            android:gravity="top|right"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" 
                            android:visibility="invisible"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/itemRecommendedText"
                                style="@style/ItemDescRecommend"
                                android:text="@string/recommended_title"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/recommendImg"
                                android:layout_gravity="top"
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/recommended_icon"
                                />

                            </LinearLayout><!-- end Layout1.1.1.2 -->

                            <!-- Layout1.1.1.3 -->
                            <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                            android:paddingRight="5dp"
                            android:gravity="top|right"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" 
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/itemCategoryText"
                                style="@style/ItemDescRecommend"
                                android:text=""
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                            </LinearLayout><!-- end Layout1.1.1.3 -->                                                                      

                            <!-- Layout1.1.1.4 -->
                            <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:visibility="invisible"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" 
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                                    <!-- Layout1.1.1.4.1 -->
                                    <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                    android:gravity="top|right"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal" 
                                    android:layout_weight="1">

                                    <RatingBar
                                    android:id="@+id/itemRating"
                                    style="@style/priceRatingBar"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:isIndicator="false"
                                    android:rating="4" />

                                    <TextView
                                    style="@style/ItemDescRecommend"
                                    android:text="@string/price_rating_title"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                    android:textSize="12sp"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                                    </LinearLayout><!-- end Layout1.1.1.4.1 -->  
                                    <!-- Layout1.1.1.4.2 -->               
                                    <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                    android:gravity="top|right"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal" 
                                    android:layout_weight="1">

                                    <RatingBar
                                    android:id="@+id/itemRating"
                                    style="@style/favoritesRatingBar"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:isIndicator="false"
                                    android:rating="4" />

                                    <TextView
                                    style="@style/ItemDescRecommend"
                                    android:text="@string/rating_title"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                    android:textSize="12sp"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                                    </LinearLayout><!-- end Layout1.1.1.4.2 -->                 

                            </LinearLayout><!-- end Layout1.1.1.4 -->                               

                            <!-- Layout1.1.1.5 -->
                            <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                            android:paddingRight="5dp"
                            android:gravity="top|right"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" 
                            android:layout_weight="1">
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/itemDistanceUnit"
                                style="@style/ItemDescRecommend"
                                android:text="ק&quot;מ"
                                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/itemDistance"
                                style="@style/ItemDescRecommend"
                                android:text="@string/restaurants_title"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/itemDistanceTitle"
                                style="@style/ItemDescRecommend"
                                android:text="@string/distance_title"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                            </LinearLayout>  <!-- end Layout1.1.5 -->

                            <!-- Layout1.1.1.6 -->                                                                 
                            <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                            android:paddingRight="5dp"
                            android:gravity="top|right"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" 
                            android:layout_weight="1">
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/itemShortDesc"
                                style="@style/ItemDescRecommend"
                                android:text=""
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                            </LinearLayout><!-- end Layout1.1.6 -->                 
                        </LinearLayout><!-- end Layout1.1.1 -->

                        <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivItemImage"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/food" />
                    </LinearLayout>
        <!-- end Layout1.1 -->  

            <!-- Layout1.2 -->
            <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                           android:id="@+id/llDirections"
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_column="1"
                           android:layout_gravity="top"
                           android:layout_weight="4"
                           android:background="@drawable/cell"
                           android:gravity="center"
                           android:orientation="horizontal" >

                           <TextView
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:gravity="center"
                               android:padding="1dip"
                               android:text="@string/direction"
                               android:textColor="#727272"
                               android:textSize="12sp" />

                           <ImageView
                               android:id="@+id/itemDirectImg"
                               android:layout_width="25dp"
                               android:layout_height="25dp"
                               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                               android:src="@drawable/action_direction_ic" />
                       </LinearLayout>        

                <LinearLayout
                           android:id="@+id/favoritesToggle"
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_gravity="top"
                           android:layout_weight="4"
                           android:background="@drawable/cell"
                           android:gravity="center"
                           android:orientation="horizontal" >

                           <TextView
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:gravity="center"
                               android:padding="1dip"
                               android:text="@string/title_feature2"
                               android:textColor="@color/ar_bg"
                               android:textSize="12sp" />

                           <ImageView
                               android:id="@+id/itemFavoriteImg"
                               android:layout_width="25dp"
                               android:layout_height="25dp"
                               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                               android:src="@drawable/action_heart_ic" />
                       </LinearLayout>              

            </LinearLayout>


            <!-- end Layout1.2 -->


            <!-- Layout 1.3 tab control-->
            <include layout="@layout/tab_control" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            <!-- end Layout 1.3 tab control-->


    </LinearLayout>             <!-- end Layout1 -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please put xml code you are using so we can help you proper for your condition.

Comment: Yes, its there now but you are declaring the style to the some LinearLayout and its not here in the code so i come to know about its properties?  Even you also incluse some layout. So its also have here to proper solution. Or for best practice Use pastebin.com to put such long code and then give the link of that code.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `wrap_content` for the height and wight properties of the top layout and add `android:layout_weight="1"` to the bottom lauyout and then see the result.
If still it not solve your issue then please put xml code so we can help you properly.

Thanks.

Comment: well, thanks first. I actualli already have these settings except the wrap_content for the top layout. I have added that but i can't check it on real device yet, so I test on the graphical layout design in the eclipse... it looks like it still not working.   I will try to add my xml here.

Comment: Yes Please put your xml here. . .  Or put it on pastebin.com and give the link of that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dp` unit for that view.